# help with choosing statistical test to compare responses to a questionnaire

Tags: r, anova, survey, intraclass-correlation, bland-altman-plot

- I have a questionnaire made of 10 questions given to doctors from different specialties.
- Each doctor evaluates 10 echocardiographic images and gives the image a score of 1-10 based on their own assessment of right heart strain.
- 30 complete responses were received (300 values, 10 columns, 30 rows)

Task 1: I would like to compare the concordance (accuracy/precision) between these 30 responses to "the control response", which is the correct assessment of right heart strain to the 10 questions in the questionnaire. (1 row with 10 values)

Task 2: I would like also to assess the responses based on the doctor's specialty (cardiologist and non-cardiologist), year of graduation, and level of confidence in reading echo.

objective: is to see whether non-cardiologist are as good as cardiologists in assessing right heart strain using echocardiography.

My initial plan is to:

- use statistical measures such as the Intraclass Correlation Coefficient (ICC) to measure the agreement between the observers and the control response.
- graph the relationship using The Bland-Altman plot which will shows the differences between the doctors' responses and the control response.
- To assess the responses based on the doctors' specialty, year of graduation, and level of confidence in reading echo, I will use descriptive statistics such as means, standard deviations, and frequencies to explore the data.
- use inferential statistics such as ANOVA or regression to test for significant differences or associations between the variables.

I would like to use R, any advice?